# Arduino connection with bluetooth hc-06

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

**Hello people**

I have a little problem. I need to connect the Arduino Mini Pro with an HC-06 Bluetooth.

input/outputs: 
**Arduino                HC-06**

GND ------------------ G(GND)

VCC --------------------- V

D0(TX)-----------------2

D1(RX) -----------------3

**I tried this code:**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");
//mySerial.begin(115200);    //if you change the baud and want to re-run this sketch, make sure this baud rate matches the new rate.
mySerial.begin(38400);
//mySerial.begin(9600);


delay(1000);
mySerial.print("AT");
delay(1000);
mySerial.print("AT+VERSION");
//delay(1000);
//mySerial.print("AT+PIN1234"); // Set pin to 1234  was 1342
//delay(1000);
//mySerial.print("AT+NAMEJY-MCU-HC06"); // Set the name to JY-MCU-HC06
delay(1000);
//mySerial.print("AT+BAUD8"); // Set baudrate to 115200
//mySerial.print("AT+BAUD4"); // Set baudrate to 9600
//mySerial.print("AT+BAUD7"); // Set baudrate to 57600
delay(1000);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
if (mySerial.available())
Serial.write(mySerial.read());
if (Serial.available())
mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

But, i can not to get the ok. Can you help me?
**Thank you.**

Comment: as you are using a Arduino Mini Pro, then you are using a vUSB Serial Port (aka FTDI). Try wiring that up to HC06 and try to talk to it over serial port. Then go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mpflaga said, the best and easiest way to debug these modules is by connecting to them directly with your computer and interfacing through a terminal program (hyperterm etc).

That being said, I'm guessing the module may be running at 9600 baud, not 38400. 
Also, I think your code would work better like:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX, TX

char myChar;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    //mySerial.begin(38400);
    mySerial.begin(9600);

    mySerial.print("AT");
    delay(1000);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
    while ( mySerial.available() )
    { 
        myChar = mySerial.read();
        Serial.print(myChar);
    }

    while ( Serial.available() )
    { 
        myChar = Serial.read();
        mySerial.print(myChar);
    }
}
```